# Set editing permission of the author in a Mediawiki

Tags: permissions, mediawiki, editing

I modified my `Localsettings.php`. Now only users can modify the pages.
Can I set this: only the author can modify his page?

Comment: There's an extension for that: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EditOwn
Also: Flagging as off topic, as not programminh related

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The entire idea of a wiki is that people collaborate. MediaWiki has no notion of a page owner or single author.

That being said, you can probably find an extension that hacks this in somehow. Try your luck here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:User_rights_extensions